# One report - 2 totals - Multiple currencies

Tags: multi-currency, currency

I am running a closed oppty report. We have Advanced Multiple Currency enabled, and some of the opptys are in INR.

When summing up the Amount and Grand Total, I get 2 different results.

[image]

So, which of the totals is the correct one?

The difference is also on a single item:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One column represents the value as it was entered, the other represents its valued after being converted according to the conversion rates set up in your ORG. So both are correct, but if you maintain the correct currency exchange rates, the converted value is probably the one you should be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because the exchange rates is no more fixed once Advanced Currency is Enabled .Based on opportunity closed dates ,the exchange rate is determined and one column represents conversion value with advanced currency feature while other one is with fixed rates .